# Emit signal when QGraphicsPathItem moves

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a class that inherits `QGraphicsPathItem`, and I'd like it to emit signals when user drags it around a `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene`. Since `QGraphicsPathItem` doesn't inherit `QObject`, this isn't possible out of the box. On the other hand, sublclasses of `QGraphicsObject` provide such signals, but don't have properties from `QGraphicsPathItem` that I need.

How can I get my `QGraphicsPathItem` subclass to emit signals when user moves it around? I've tried:

- Multiple inheritance, with my class inheriting both `QGraphicsPathItem` and `QGraphicsObject`
- Creating a child `QGraphicsObject` within my `QGraphicsPathItem`

I'm using `pyside`.

Comment: It depends on what you need that reference for, and what makes more sense in the object hierarchy. In cases like these, I sometimes put the graphics item *in* the graphics object, so that I have direct access to the QObject and its signals, and eventually add convenience functions to address the properties of the actual graphics item. Alternatively, just create a "proxy" QObject class with the custom signal, create a new instance in the `__init__` of the graphics item and emit its signal whenever you need it.

Comment: From where can I emit the custom signal? My initial problem is that I have no callback being invoked when the GraphicsPathItem is being moved. Otherwise, I wouldn't delve in the QObject stuff in the first place.

Comment: Set the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag, override [`itemChange()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) and check for `ItemPositionHasChanged` changes, then emit the signal with the value.